# Can't add text to TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I'm working on Fragments with ViewPager and PageAdapter, and want to dynamically add content to the fragments depending on which parent node is clicked. The MainActivity sends data and this Activity receives it like this:

`intent.putExtra("biz_data", biz_data);`,

`intent.getStringArrayExtra("biz_data");`

However I'm unable to edit the content of the fragment layouts. You can see at end of the Activity I'm trying to do this, but it is giving me an error:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.today_frag_tv);
// tv.setEnabled(true); // gives error
// tv.append("new stuff"); // gives error
// tv.setText("MY Custom Stuff"); // gives error`
```

---

**Full Activity Code**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

/**
 * Demonstrates a "screen-slide" animation using a {@link ViewPager}. Because {@link ViewPager}
 * automatically plays such an animation when calling {@link ViewPager#setCurrentItem(int)}, there
 * isn't any animation-specific code in this sample.
 *
 * <p>This sample shows a "next" button that advances the user to the next step in a wizard,
 * animating the current screen out (to the left) and the next screen in (from the right). The
 * reverse animation is played when the user presses the "previous" button.</p>
 *
 * @see ScreenSlidePageFragment
 */
public class ScreenSlideActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

    /* The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.*/
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

    /* The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
     * and next wizard steps.*/
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /* The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.*/
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        final String biz_data[] = in.getStringArrayExtra("biz_data");


        set_fragment_data(biz_data);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onFragClick (View view){
        Toast.makeText(ScreenSlideActivity.this, "button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_screen_slide, menu);

        // enable 'prev' and 'next' when not on first node
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_prev).setEnabled(mPager.getCurrentItem() > 0);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_next).setEnabled(mPager.getCurrentItem() < (NUM_PAGES-1));

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 16908332:
                // Navigate "up" the demo structure to the launchpad activity.
                // See http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html for more.
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_prev:
                // Go to the previous step in the wizard. If there is no previous step,
                // setCurrentItem will do nothing.
                mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_next:
                // Advance to the next step in the wizard. If there is no next step, setCurrentItem
                // will do nothing.
                mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 {@link ScreenSlidePageFragment} objects, in
     * sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }

    public void set_fragment_data(String biz_data[]){
        // title as business name
        setTitle(biz_data[1]);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.today_frag_tv);
//        tv.setEnabled(true);
//        tv.append("new stuff");

//        tv.setText("MY Custom Stuff");

    }
}
```

Comment: The code to change the fragments content should be put in the fragment.

Comment: I must be doing it wrong because I'm still getting an error. When setting a layout to a fragment, I do this: `rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_business, container, false);`. However I'm having trouble adding content to it. Also, I seemingly can't use the function findviewById(), says "can't resolve method".

Comment: Have you tried using `findViewById()` on the View of the fragment? In your case, like `rootView.findViewById(R.id.today_frag_tv)`?

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As prescribed by Benjamin Scharbau, this has solved my problem:

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_business, container, false);

TextView tv = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.today_frag_tv);

tv.setText("text");
```